# How to steps differences reduce in Hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

How to steps differences reduce in Hadoop?
I have a problem with understand Hadoop. I have two files and first I did a join between those files. One file is about countries and the other is about client in each country.
Example, clients.csv:

```
Bertram Pearcy  ,bueno,SO
Steven Ulman  ,regular,ZA
```

Countries.csv

```
Name,Code   
Afghanistan,AF
Ã…land Islands,AX
Albania,AL  
…
```

I did one map reduce that give me how many “good” (bueno) clients have a country (ZA, SO) and with countries.csv I know with country we are talking.

I programmed:

```
def steps(self): 
        # ordenamos las operaciones para su ejecución.
        return [ 
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper 
                   ,reducer=self.reducer),            
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper1
                   ,combiner=self.combiner_cuenta_palabras
                   ,reducer=self.reducer2
                    ),
        ]
```

The result of my map/reduce is:

```
["South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"]    1
["South Sudan"] 1
["Spain"]   3
```

Now, I would like to know which one is the best.

I added one reduce more.

```
    def reducer3(self, _, values):            
        yield  _, max (values)
        
    def steps(self): 
        # ordenamos las operaciones para su ejecución.
        return [ 
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper 
                   ,reducer=self.reducer),  
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper1
                   ,combiner=self.combiner_cuenta_palabras
                   ,reducer=self.reducer2),
            MRStep(#mapper=self.mapper3,
                   reducer=self.reducer3
                   #,reducer=self.reducer3
            ),            
        ]
```

But I have the same answer than without that reducer

---

I try to use one map/reduce program adding another reduce. It that does not work.

With my first reduce I got:

```
A, 10
C, 2
D, 5
```

Now, I would like to use that result I get:
A, 10

Additional comment:

INPUT [Fille1]+[File2]    =>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uViQK.png)

MAP/REDUCE => OUT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VT1i.png)

Now, I need that with additional map/reduce ( and I would like to use what I did) get another answers.

First) For instance, one and only one answer. Example:      `3    Spain`

Second) All with the best or bigger number, `3 Spain` and `3 Guan`.

I try to use:

```
def reducer3(self, _, values):            
        yield  _, max (values)
```

And I add,

```
def steps(self): 
        # ordenamos las operaciones para su ejecución.
        return [ 
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper 
                   ,reducer=self.reducer),  
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper1
                   ,combiner=self.combiner_cuenta_palabras
                   ,reducer=self.reducer2),
            MRStep(reducer=self.reducer3
            ),            
        ]
```

But I still have the same result. I Know that REDUCER3 is using because if I write `max(values)+1000` give me the same result but with number `1001`, `1003`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer is getting 3 distinct keys, therefore you're finding the max of each, and `values` only has one element (try printing its length... ). Therefore, you get 3 results.

You need a third mapper that returns `(None, f'{key}|{value})` for example, then all records will be sent to **one reducer**, where you can then iterate, parse, and aggregate the results

```py
def reducer3(self, _, values):
    _max = float('-inf')
    k_out = None
    for x in values:
        k, v = x.split('|')
        if int(v) > _max:
            _max = v
            k_out = k
    yield  k_out, _max
```

That'll only return one result for all values. If you want to capture equal max values, I think you'll need to iterate over the list more than once, then yield within a loop of found max elements

Comment: Thank you . I did One mapper new and two reducer ( first sum and second max) and it works. But thanks to you know I understand why it didn´t work with my first way to do it. Thank you.